# How to form sentences with feel like

Tags: grammar

Are there any differences between the following sentences:

1- I feel like I am a teacher.

(and)

I feel like a teacher.

2- I feel like I have made a mistake.

(and)

I feel like having made a mistake.

3- I feel like I am eating.

(and)

I feel like eating.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- I feel like I am a teacher.
>
> I feel like a teacher.

These mean the same.  In theory, "I feel like a teacher" might mean that you were in the mood for eating a teacher, but more often it means the same thing as "I feel like I am a teacher".

Either way, you might be a teacher (and you now feel like one too), or you might be a non-teacher who feels like one.

> 2- I feel like I have made a mistake.
>
> I feel like having made a mistake.

The second sentence is of dubious grammaticality.  We'd only use it as part of a larger sentence ("I feel like having made a mistake I should now apologise").

> 3- I feel like I am eating.
>
> I feel like eating.

The first one means that you have the impression or illusion that you're eating, but you're not.  The second one means that you are in the mood to eat something.